# Android: Animation in Gallery View?

Tags: android, image, android-animation, gallery

When I use the **Gallery widget**, how do I get the images to say **scale up** & **glow** on being selected and **scaled down** & **un-glow** on being *unselected*?

All tutorials I've seen have this effect but I'm not able to see it...

Is there some kind of an **animation** that I have to attach to the **Gallery**?

Comment: i am doing same thing but it is not working in some android devices, if you have achieve this animation in gallery view, please send me code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hope this is helpful. I manage to "simulate" the shrink/grow solution with the `Gallery` widget. Since they removed the `getScale()`, things get a little bit complicated. I think that this it's not the best solution at all, but at least I can live with it.

What I have found is that `Gallery` manages the focus EXTREMELY BAD. So, the first approach was to add a focus change listener on the `ImageView` displayed, but no luck there. Focus is a MESS there... in terms that, the selected image it's not the currently focused view. I have sent a mail to android-developers mailing list about some error on API doc (regarding the `focusSearch()`method and some focus contants).

Here's my solution to this problem:

Build an animation resource to 'grow' the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:toXScale="1.10"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="1.10"
       android:duration="300"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fillAfter="false"/>
```

If you don't get what that means then you should proceed to read [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

That will be our 'grow' effect, and you will need to save it in: `res/anim/grow.xml` or whatever name it suites you (but always in res/anim dir).

You can follow the resource guide from [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) to create a `Gallery` view. The `ImageAdapter` builds an `ImageView` every time that the `Gallery` object calls `getView()`. One workaround you could implement is adding a line to the `getView()` method that identifies a `View` with a `position`, this way:

```
...
i.setId(position);
...
```

With that line added to the `getView()` method of the `ImageAdpater` object, you can then unequivocally identify that view within a listener, for instance:

```
g.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void  onItemSelected  (AdapterView<?>  parent, View  v, int position, long id) {
        Animation grow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourActivity.this, R.anim.grow);

        View sideView = parent.findViewById(position - 1);
        if (sideView != null)
           ((ImageView)sideView).setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));

        sideView = parent.findViewById(position + 1);
        if (sideView != null)
           ((ImageView)sideView).setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));

        v.startAnimation(grow);
        v.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(170, 150));
    }

    public void  onNothingSelected  (AdapterView<?>  parent) {
        System.out.println("NOTHING SELECTED");

    }
    });
```

NOTE: You may notice that all the values from animation and from layout parameters has been choosen by me at hand. This is because i'm not going to clean code for you. And, this is just a workaround the BAD focus issue with this widget or the android view system. If focus were OK, then, all you need to do is set a focus change listener that makes the gros/shrink when it got focus/unfocused.

I hope this may help you to find a way around for your problem,

Regards,

New EDIT: This is the listener I have set, I also added the line `i.clearAnimation()` in the `getView()` method:

```
private class SelectListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
     private Animation grow;
     private int last;

     public SelectListener() {
        grow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(RouteGallery.this, R.anim.grow);
        last = 0;
     }

     public void  onItemSelected  (AdapterView<?>  parent, View  v, int position, long id) {
        View sideView = parent.findViewById(last);
        if (sideView != null && last != position)
           sideView.clearAnimation();

        v.startAnimation(grow);
        last = position;
     }

    public void  onNothingSelected  (AdapterView<?>  parent) {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Did not see this. Accepted as answer. Thanks for your time guys! Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use an ImageSwitcher.  The ImageSwitcher has methods for setting the in and out animations (when image is selected and deselected, or selected and replaced).

The [following link](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views) has a good tutorial on how to use it in conjunction with the Gallery.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice it but I still could not find a way to scale up and scale down the images in the imageswitcher itself... What I mean is the top portion that is visible... When clicked, it should give us a normal size else a reduced size... Am I missing some trivial solution?

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a similar animation like this:

```
final Animation shrink = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.shrink);
shrink.setFillAfter(true);

gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // This iterates through the views which are currently displayed on screen.
            for (int k=0; k<gallery.getChildCount(); k++){
                // Do whatever else you want, here.
                // This is how you get a particular element of a view
                ImageView background = (ImageView) gallery.getChildAt(k).findViewById(R.id.menu_item_background);

                //clear animation
                gallery.getChildAt(k).clearAnimation();

            }

            // Scale the selected one
            view.startAnimation(shrink);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}

    });
```